# Metadata reverted and I don’t understand why

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

It’s the fifth time that’s I send it to review and I get all time only this massage... and I don’t understand this. Any one can helping me..? A German developer need a explanation pls.

3. - 1.2 Business: Payments - Subscriptions

Thank you for your resubmission.

After further review we still notice that the previous issue has not been addressed yet and the app description is missing necessary information.

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

We still noticed that your app did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

App Store Information
We were unable to find all of the required information within your metadata.

We were unable to find a link to your Terms of Use in either the app description or EULA field of App Store Connect.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include this missing information. If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it. Please ensure that the Terms of Use link is included in both the metadata (the app description or EULA field of App Store Connect) and in the app binary.

Resources

The Apple Developer website includes detailed resources on how to offer auto-renewable subscriptions in your app. You can learn more about creating a positive onboarding experience for your customers in the Subscriptions Human Interface Guidelines.

Request a phone call from App Review

At your request, we can arrange for an Apple Representative to call you within the next three to five business days to discuss your App Review issue.

Request a call to discuss your app's review

Since your App Store Connect status is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. To revise the metadata, visit App Store Connect to select your app and revise the desired metadata values. Once you’ve completed all changes, reply to this message in Resolution Center and we will continue the review.

Comment: Is your app a paid-app? Did you paste this link (https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/dev/stdeula/) in the description?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to have a "terms of use" website that users can hit.  You need to point to that in your app description.  To edit your app description:

1. Sign in to AppStoreConnect.apple.com
2. Select "My Apps"
3. Select the "App Store" tab
4. Select the version of your app on the left column under the "iOS APP" heading
5. Edit the Description, putting in your link to your "terms of use".

Comment: I chose the standard license from apple .. I have now copied the link of apple standard license into the body .. we will talk again later. I copy this link https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/dev/stdeula/ and pasted this 1:1 in the Body.

Comment: Thanks Sir ! My app is now im AppStore 

Comment: I have same issue and that resolved now, Thank you.

Comment: @Aiiboo Hello, i have the exacly same problem as you, when you said "pasted this 1:1 in the body", you pasted this inside your code or in the description of your app in appstore?

Comment: In the description of your app in the App Store.

Answer (score 15):

**I had to put below content in the end of the description and got green signal from store.**

"Your App Title Name" subscription "Name of feature you are providing".

"Your App Title Name" plans:

- Monthly: $1.99
- Annual: $9.99

Payments and Renewal:

- Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase.
  Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period.
- Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period.
- You can manage or turn off auto-renew in your Account settings at any time after purchase
- No cancellation of the current subscription is allowed during the active period.

Terms of use: http://yourappwebsite.com/your-app-terms-conditions.html.
Privacy policy: http://yourappwebsite.com/your-app-privacy-policy.html

Comment: In the app store app description right?

Answer (score 1):

Your app will need to link to the privacy policy and terms of use (!) from within the app, app store description or similar. You cannot just re-use the exact same EULA from Apple. (Terms of use are not the same as end user license agreement in the context of auto-renewables.)

Quoting from the Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement:

> (b) You clearly and conspicuously disclose to users the following information regarding Your auto-renewing
>   subscription:
>
> • Title of auto-renewing subscription, which may be the same as the in-app product name
>
> • Length of subscription
>
> • Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate
>
> Links to Your Privacy Policy and **Terms of Use** must be accessible within your Licensed Application

I think the reviewer is looking for the last point (highlighted).

For a detailed guide, check out: https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/apple-will-reject-your-subscription-app-if-you-dont-include-this-disclosure

Comment: Thank you for your help!  but then I do not understand why you can choose the standard license from Apple. 

Comment: That is the EULA for the app itself. It has nothing to do with subscriptions. Subscriptions need more "legalese" and therefore require your own terms of service. These are two different things. Maybe a lawyer can help you better understand the difference between the two.

Comment: it has resolved itself.  the tip from HaIR helped .. it was enough with the standard Apple license and add the link in the description